# multiple targets white-labeling

Tags: xcode, white-labelling

what is the best way to handle many targets. i'm building a white label app that will have hundreds of brands, and build targets that are based on the same bundle.

key data that needs to change between labels are

1. Image or Asset Cataloges
2. plist files
3. app entitlements
4. Signing certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I would recommend:

- Have different targets for different entitlements and signing
  certificates. They can all utilize the same code, by being in the
  same Xcode project.
- For the plist files and image catalogs, you can load upon first startup or have them downloaded at first start (see more here on
  downloading: [Installing App-Specific Data Files at First Launch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9) -